# after outlook 2010 grade from 2007 the month calendar display at top of navigator missing

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

After the 2010 office upgrade, Outlook will not display the month calendar above the mailbox and folder list in folder view as it did in 2007 except when I have the calendar folder open. If I open the inbox folder, that month display disappears. How can I get the month display to stick no matter what folder I am looking at? Im using folder view and I have disabled the todo option in the view tab.

Answer (score 0):

The calendar only appears in the mail views when you have the right-hand "To-Do Bar" open. You can deselect the "Task List" display but make sure that "Date Navigator" is selected.

You also need to make sure that the bar is not minimised. There is a small right or left facing arrow in the top line of the Navigation Bar that minimises or restores it. Dragging the || arrow at the edge of the Bar has the same effect.

This setting controls the view for everything except the calendar view.